# проблема с наследованием через конструктор

Tags: javascript

[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/pt40sppd/2/) наследования:

есть 2 конструктора: Game, Level. на их основе я создаю 2 объекта, таким образом, чтобы level наследовался от game:

```
var Game = function(parentGameElementTag) {
  this.parentGameElementTag = parentGameElementTag;
  this.gameElementId = 'game';
  this.levelObj = new Level();  

  this.init();
};

Game.prototype = {
  init: function() {  
    $('<div class="game" id="' + this.gameElementId + '"></div>').appendTo(this.parentGameElementTag);   
  }
 };

 var Level = function() { 
  var self = this;

  this.fieldElementId = 'field';  
  this.levelScreenDisplay('body');  
};

//Level.prototype = Game;
Level.prototype = Object.create(Game.prototype);

Level.prototype = {

  levelScreenDisplay: function(parentElementTag) {
    $('<div class="level_begin_label" id="levelBeginLabel">Уровень: ' + this.level + '</div>').appendTo(parentElementTag);   

    setTimeout(function() { 
      $('<div class="any_key_invitation" id="anyKeyInvitation">Нажмите любую клавишу для старта</div>').appendTo('#levelBeginLabel');

      document.onkeypress = function() {
        document.onkeypress = undefined;
        $('#levelBeginLabel').remove();
      };          
    }, 1000);
  }
};

var app = new Game('body');
```

в результате на странице должен выводиться номер уровня. которого нет в level, но который есть в game. а благодаря наследованию он должен найтись. но не находится. в чём я ошибаюсь?

Comment: не видно где вы создаете второй объект

Comment: здесь: this.levelObj = new Level();

Comment: а зачем вам в этом случае вообще наследовать Level от Game?

Comment: у меня будет игра. в game(инстансе от Game) будет содержаться вся основная информация: количество жизней, номер уровня и т.д., а level(инстанс от Level) будет создаваться каждый раз новый. после того как уровень проходится, level уничтожается, меняется информация  в game и затем опять создаётся новый level.

необходимо чтобы в процессе игры level имел доступ к переменным game

Comment: в таком случае, мне кажется вам не нужно наследование. Посмотрите мой обновленный ответ

Comment: спасибо, я пометил задачу как решённую. но вообще говоря, наследование нужно. например на определённом уровне игрок взял приз и появилась необходимость добавить очков. переменная с количеством очков с вою очередь содержится в game(так как она не может создаваться каждый раз заново с новым уровнем). как в этом случае обратиться из level в game чтобы изменить количество очков? только через наследование

Comment: Основы конечно знать хорошо, но не проще взять какую-нибудь либу решающую задачу наследования: [Раз](https://github.com/dkraczkowski/js.class), [Два](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/packages.html)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34693/discussion-between-grundy-and-cyklop77).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что свойства *level* нет ни в одном из *классов* поэтому всегда выводится *undefiend*.

Кроме того в данном случае не нужно наследование. Проще указать это свойство через конструктор.

```js
var Game = function(parentGameElementTag) {
  this.parentGameElementTag = parentGameElementTag;
  this.gameElementId = 'game';
  this.levelObj = new Level(1);

  this.init();
};

Game.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $('<div class="game" id="' + this.gameElementId + '"></div>').appendTo(this.parentGameElementTag);
  }
};

var Level = function(level) {
  var self = this;
  this.level = level;

  this.fieldElementId = 'field';
  this.levelScreenDisplay('body');
};

Level.prototype = {

  levelScreenDisplay: function(parentElementTag) {
    $('<div class="level_begin_label" id="levelBeginLabel">Уровень: ' + this.level + '</div>').appendTo(parentElementTag);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('<div class="any_key_invitation" id="anyKeyInvitation">Нажмите любую клавишу для старта</div>').appendTo('#levelBeginLabel');

      document.onkeypress = function() {
        document.onkeypress = undefined;
        $('#levelBeginLabel').remove();
      };
    }, 1000);
  }
};

var app = new Game('body');
```

```css
.level_begin_label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px arial, sans-serif;
}
.any_key_invitation {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.game {
  /* position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;*/
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** обновление после комментария.
В данном случае проще всего сохранить ссылку на Game внутри создаваемого объекта Level.

```js
var Game = function(parentGameElementTag) {
  this.parentGameElementTag = parentGameElementTag;
  this.gameElementId = 'game';
  this.level = 1; //например
  this.levelObj = new Level(this); // передаем ссылку game объекта в конструктор для уровня

  this.init();
};

Game.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $('<div class="game" id="' + this.gameElementId + '"></div>').appendTo(this.parentGameElementTag);
  }
};

var Level = function(game) {
  var self = this;
  this.level = game.level; // можно опустить эту строучку и получать значение через this.game.level
  this.game = game;
  this.fieldElementId = 'field';
  this.levelScreenDisplay('body');
};

Level.prototype = {

  levelScreenDisplay: function(parentElementTag) {
    $('<div class="level_begin_label" id="levelBeginLabel">Уровень: ' + this.level + '</div>').appendTo(parentElementTag);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('<div class="any_key_invitation" id="anyKeyInvitation">Нажмите любую клавишу для старта</div>').appendTo('#levelBeginLabel');

      document.onkeypress = function() {
        document.onkeypress = undefined;
        $('#levelBeginLabel').remove();
      };
    }, 1000);
  }
};

var app = new Game('body');
```

```css
.level_begin_label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px arial, sans-serif;
}
.any_key_invitation {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.game {
  /* position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;*/
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: так не получается: https://jsfiddle.net/pt40sppd/3/

Comment: это да :-) проглядел что вы в _базовом_ классе создаете экземпляр класс наследника. Не совсем похоже на наследование :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
// для определения наследования 
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null 
                  ? Object.create(b) 
                  : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
```

---

```
var Game = (function () {
    function Game(tag) {
        this.init();
    }
    Game.prototype.init = function () { 
       // ...
    };
    Object.defineProperty(Game.prototype, "LevelNumber", {
        get: function () {
            return 123;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Game;
})();

// Level наследует Game
var Level = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Level, _super);
    function Level(tag) {
        _super.call(this, tag);
    }
    return Level;
})(Game);
```

---

```
var lvl = new Level("body");
alert(lvl.LevelNumber);  // выводит: 123  -- LevelNumber определен в Game
```