# jquery создание html элементов через конструктор

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть функция `Element` и `Element.prototype.draw`, использующийся для создания формы и инпута в этой форме. Совершенно запутался в присвоении. т.е. конструктор `InputElement` наследует Елемент и добавляет своё поле `type` к инпутам, но я, к сожалению, не понимаю как мне правильно задать в `Element.prototype.draw` строку с `InputElement` которая бы добавляла этот `type`.

```
function Element (name, template, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.classes = ["formClass"];
    this.template = template;
};
// debugger;
function InputElement (name, template, type) {
    Element.call(this);
    this.type = type;
};
Element.prototype.draw = function (parentElement) {
    $Element = $(this.template);
    $Element.attr("name", this.name);
    $Element.addClass(this.classes.join(""));
    $Element.attr("type",)
    $(parentElement).prepend($Element);
    return $Element;
};

var testForm = new Element("form", "<form></form>");
var testInput = new Element("input", "<input></input>", "password");
testForm.draw("body");
testInput.draw("form");
```

Comment: см. пример наследования в javascript -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484921/196972)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
function Element (name, template, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;                                // <-- добавлена строка
    this.classes = ["formClass"];
    this.template = template;
};
// debugger;
function InputElement (name, template, type) {
    Element.call(this);
    this.type = type;
};
Element.prototype.draw = function (parentElement) {
    $Element = $(this.template);
    $Element.attr("name", this.name);
    $Element.addClass(this.classes.join(""));
    if( this.type) $Element.attr("type", this.type); // <-- исправлена строка
    $(parentElement).prepend($Element);
    return $Element;
};

var testForm = new Element("form", "<form></form>");
var testInput = new Element("input", "<input></input>", "password");
testForm.draw("body");
testInput.draw("form");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Улучшение**

jQuery позволяет создавать элемент HTML с передачей объекта его атрибутов в такой сигнатуре: [`jQuery( element, attributes)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes). Поскольку нет принципиальной разницы между атрибутами *name*, *type* и, например, *id*, *class* и другими, которые, возможно, захочется передавать в скором будущем, может, стоит передавать в ваши функции объект свойств? Примерно так:

```
function Element (template, attributes) {
    if(typeof attributes === "object") {
      for( var prop in attributes) {
        this[prop] = attributes[prop];
      }
    }
    this.template = template || "<div/>"; // по умолчанию div
};

// создавать элементв в prototype.draw:
$Element = $(this.template, this.attributes);

// и вызывать:
var testForm = new Element("<form/>", {name: "form"});
var testInput = new Element("<input/>", {name:"form", type:"password"});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь. А можно ли сделать через input.Element? Через Елемент проще, но как можно это сделать из конструктора , который наследует Element?